# Reducer add item and update item in array of objects without mutation

Tags: javascript, redux

Hello created reducer and wondering is this right pattern.

I am trying to:

1. Add new item into array of objects **ACTION_TYPE**
2. Update item in array of objects **ACTION_TYPE_EDIT**, this one actually should set **charity** prop and update item in array **charities**

Wondering if i am on right path, i don't want to mutate, so here is my code.

```
export const reducerCharities = (
  state: CharityReducerState,
  action: CharitiesAction
    | CharityEditAction
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPE_EDIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        charity: {
          ...state.charity,
          ...(action.charity || {}),
        },
        charities: [
          ...state.charities.map(item => item.id === action.charity?.id ? { ...item, ...action.charity } : item)
        ]
      }
    case ACTION_TYPE:
      return {
        ...state,
        charities: [
          ...state.charities || [],
          ...action.charities
        ]
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So my question is will this part mutate state or is there better way to write this?

```
charities: [
          ...state.charities.map(item => item.id === action.charity?.id ? { ...item, ...action.charity } : item)
        ]
```

Is this right approach how to add new item into array

```
     {
        ...state,
        charities: [
          ...state.charities || [],
          ...action.charities
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and since 2019 officially recommended) way of doing this would be using the official Redux Toolkit package and the `createSlice` method.

Within that, you can just mutate and don't have to care about manual immutable updates - the package takes over for you.

The code could look like

```
const charitiesSlice = ({
  name: 'charities',
  initialStae: myInitialState,
  reducers: {
    edit(state, action: PayloadAction<Charity>){
      const charity = state.charities.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id)
      if (charity) {
        Object.assign(charity, action.payload)
      }
      state.charity = action.payload
    }
  }
}
 
export const { edit } = charitiesSlice.actions
export const reducerCharities = charitiesSlice.reducer
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve this without  official Redux Toolkit package?

Comment: By writing tons of immutable code - someone else will probably also answer with the code for that. But I just can really recommend not doing that. You are writing a style of Redux here that will end up being about 5 times as much code as following recommended patterns and it will end up to be absolutely unreadable. Please follow the official recommendation - a good start is the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).